# Minimum_should_match not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Match Query:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "nAME":{  
                     "analyzer":"my_fuzzy_analyzer",
                     "fuzziness":"AUTO:1,4",
                     "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                     "max_expansions":2147483647,
                     "minimum_should_match":-1,
                     "operator":"and",
                     "prefix_length":3,
                     "query":"SHENZHEN LONGTANUO LOGISTICS C "
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

`

Expected Results:

- SHENZHEN LONGTANUO LOGISTICS C
- SHENZHEN LUCKY LOGISTICS LTD.
- SHENZHEN UNIQUE LOGISTICS INTERNATIONAL LTD.

Note : International - ltd - logistics are stopword ,

But only get result :
SHENZHEN LONGTANUO LOGISTICS C

I couldnt understand why. Beause every text have -1 match

Analyzer :
`

```
{  
   "atlas.zcustomer":{  
      "settings":{  
         "index":{  
            "number_of_shards":"5",
            "provided_name":"atlas.zcustomer",
            "creation_date":"1563288936515",
            "analysis":{  
               "filter":{  
                  "my_stop_word":{  
                     "type":"stop",
                     "stopwords":[  
                        "ith",
                        "ihr",
                        "san",
                        "tic",
                        "ltd",
                        "de",
                        "la",
                        "s",
                        "a",
                        "inc",
                        "logistics",
                        "international"
                     ]
                  },
                  "my_length":{  
                     "type":"length",
                     "min":"3"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer":{  
                  "my_fuzzy_analyzer":{  
                     "filter":[  
                        "my_length",
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_stop_word"
                     ],
                     "type":"custom",
                     "tokenizer":"standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
            "uuid":"KVI55mDhS4mtumpOqp4mjw",
            "version":{  
               "created":"6060099"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The number of required match is relative to the number of terms in your query. In your example you have 3 terms (using standard tokenizer and stopwords) :

- SHENZHEN
- LONGTANUO
- C

So at least 2 terms must match. In your example, only one term match because `LOGISTICS` is in the stopwords. I hope it is more clear for you.

Comment: I have length filter Min(3) , so "C" is not a token , I just only have 2 terms

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Are your analyzers applied both during at indexation and query ?

Comment: thanks for applying , I just have analyzer in query

Comment: Serach on

* SHENZHEN UNIQUE LOGISTICS INTERNATIONAL LTD.

3 match , as expected but others not return all